# How to make slide presentation cover full screen in blogger

Tags: slideshow

I want to embed a [google slide presentation](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1_PYlJfYcPGhCkRQOi9S7iEdCVfE42DWuRexzGQ8wzgA/edit?usp=sharing) in blogger and write a code for that.

```html
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/e/2PACX-1vSqBslhSm-a_WKavLAyqHjKCXj84-Aeo738t4DHQuVPfdiq_7rbl7SOhteqNAwi6IlGS7pIbnofac5g/embed?start=true&loop=true&delayms=3000" frameborder="0" width="960" height="569" allowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

and that's how it is looking in mobile view.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7zIX.png)

How can i remove that black part upper and below and fit the presentation over entire screen without any top or bottom margin ?

Edit: On writing another code

```html
``<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/e/2PACX-1vSqBslhSm-a_WKavLAyqHjKCXj84-Aeo738t4DHQuVPfdiq_7rbl7SOhteqNAwi6IlGS7pIbnofac5g/embed?start=true&loop=true&delayms=3000" frameborder="0" width="960" height="569" allowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>``
```

It is looking like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYyOc.png) in pc. How to fit it into entire screen.

Comment: You might need to change "Page Setup" (In the menu under File/... ) to match your screen size.